# Scanf repeats itself in C

Tags: c

This is a simple program in which the user enters a series of numbers which are then added. The result is printed on the screen. Here's the code:

```
int main() {
int * numbers;
int result = 0;
int howMany;
int i;

printf("How many numbers would you like to add?\n");
scanf(" %d\n", &howMany);

numbers = (int *) malloc(howMany * sizeof(int));

for(i = 0; i < howMany; i++){
    printf("Please enter number %d.\n", i + 1);
    scanf(" %d\n", &numbers[i]);
    result = result + numbers [i];
}
printf("Result: %d", result);
return 0;
}
```

But there is a problem. The program asks for how many numbers the user would like to add twice for some reason. Why is that? How can I fix it? 
Also, not sure if this is related but the results also make no sense. Sometimes they are correct, other times they aren't, not sure why either.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of an space before `%d` and `\n` after `%d` in `scanf`?

Comment: Remove the `\n` from both `scanf` statements and it will work fine (subject to checking the return value from `scanf` but that is another issue).

Comment: Step 1: whenever code is having an issue with `scanf()`: check its return value.  That will not solve the issue here, but it should be the first thing tried.

Comment: If the purpose it to add the numbers input, then you don't even need an array. You only need three variables,  `howMany` and `thisNumber` and `result`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The program asks for how many numbers the user would like to add twice for some reason. Why is that? How can I fix it?

Your program prompts me only once for how many numbers.  It does, however, defer asking for each specific number until after I enter it, and then it requires an extra non-blank line after the last (late) prompt before it outputs the result.

> Also, not sure if this is related but the results also make no sense. Sometimes they are correct, other times they aren't, not sure why either.

It is related: the fact that the per-number prompts are late is confusing you about which numbers are being added.

This all comes down to your `scanf()` formats, as @Mark already remarked (albeit somewhat tersely).  Any nonempty run of whitespace, including newlines, in a `scanf()` format matches a possibly-empty run of whitespace.  When it is matching such a run, `scanf()` has to keep scanning until it sees a non-whitespace character.  Interactive input is line-buffered, however, so no new input is available to it until you send a whole new line.  Then the first non-whitespace character on that next line is ready and waiting for the *following* `scanf()`.

`scanf()` can be quite tricky to use correctly, especially for interactive input.  It is best suited for fixed-format input.  You *can* do this with `scanf()` -- @Mark showed you how -- but the usual recommendation around here is to use `fgets()` to read input one line at a time, and `sscanf()` (or your choice of other mechanism) to parse each line.  Even that can be a challenge to make bullet-proof, but you start out on firmer footing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was because of your erroneous placement of the newline characters in your printf and scanf functions.

Here is the code you are probably looking for:

```
int main() {
  int * numbers;
  int result = 0;
  int howMany;
  int i;

  printf("How many numbers would you like to add?: ");
  scanf("%d", &howMany);

  numbers = (int *) malloc(howMany * sizeof(int));

  for(i = 0; i < howMany; i++){
    printf("Please enter number %d: ", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
    result = result + numbers [i];
  }
  printf("Result: %d\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @usr - true - `scanf()` lives in the dark murky swamp of coding quagmires.